# Identify large tile sticker with flaming monster

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I have a large tile (inclined) with a sticker of what looks like a fire monster with flames. Can you help me identifying the set? Could it be a Ninjago set?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This stickered [Slope 10 6 x 8](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4515&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)
comes from

[9464: The Vampyre Hearse](https://brickset.com/sets/9464-1/The-Vampyre-Hearse)

[image]

Comment: Lovely, many thanks!